# python In the chat program, I have to press enter to see the message of the 2nd person, how can I do this in real time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When 2 people connect to the script, the second person needs to press enter to see their message. how can i do this in real time

Or is there an error on the code screen I have written, I do not fully understand, is there anyone who can help

here are the client.py source codes

```
import sys
import errno
import select
import socket
from pip._vendor.colorama import Fore

HEADER_LENGHT = 10
IP = "localhost"
PORT = 2021

print(Fore.WHITE+"|"+Fore.YELLOW+"chat"+Fore.WHITE+"|")
print()

my_username = input(Fore.WHITE+"|"+Fore.YELLOW+"Username"+Fore.WHITE+"|"+ Fore.WHITE+" > ")
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP,PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode("utf-8")
username_header = F"{len(username): <{HEADER_LENGHT}}".encode("utf-8")
client_socket.send(username_header+username)

while True:
    message = input(f"{my_username} > ")

    if message:
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        message_header = f"{len(message) : < {HEADER_LENGHT}}".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)
    try:
        while True:
        
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGHT)
            if not len(username_header):
                print("connection closed by the server")
                sys.exit()
            username_length = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode("utf-8")

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGHT)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")

            print(f"{username} > {message}")

    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error',str(e))
            sys.exit()
        continue
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('General error',str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

here are the server.py source codes

```
    import socket
import select
from pip._vendor.colorama import Fore

HEADER_LENGHT = 10
IP = "localhost"
PORT = 2021

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind((IP,PORT))
server_socket.listen()
sockets_list = [server_socket]
clients = {}

print(Fore.RED+"Server Activated")

def recieve_message(client_socket):
    try:
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGHT)

        if not len(message_header):
            return False

        message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
        return {"header": message_header, "data": client_socket.recv(message_length)}

    except:
        return False

while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)
    
    for notified_sockets in read_sockets:
        if notified_sockets == server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            
            user = recieve_message(client_socket)
            if user is False:
                continue
            sockets_list.append(client_socket)
            
            clients[client_socket] = user
            
            print(Fore.BLUE+f"Accepted new connection From {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} username:{user['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

        else:
            message = recieve_message(notified_sockets)

            if message is False:
                print(f"Closed connection from{clients[notified_sockets]['data'].decode('utf-8')}")
                sockets_list.remove(notified_sockets)
                del clients[notified_sockets]
                continue
            
            user = clients[notified_sockets]
            print(f"Recieved message from {user['data'].decode('utf-8')}: {message['data'].decode('utf-8')}")

            for client_socket in clients:
                if client_socket != notified_sockets:
                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])


for notified_sockets in exception_sockets:
    sockets_list.remove(notified_sockets)
    del clients[notified_sockets]
```

Comment: You can't use `input` for this. It returns after enter is pressed. Start your search here: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&q=python+read+key+pressed&oq=python+read+key+press&aqs=heirloom-srp.0.0l3

Comment: I'm sending a message, the other side is sending a message, but his message is not visible on my screen. I need to send 1 more message to see the message.